# Embedding HTML anchors to title created using ODS HTML in SAS

Tags: html, sas

With ODS HTML in SAS, I would like to create anchors to titles so that I could refer to those anchors from tables.

Currently I have been able to create references in the tables:

```
proc sql;
select '<a href="#'||m.anchor_text||'">'||m.anchor_text||'</a>'
  from matrix m;
quit;
```

which in HTML browser output will show as internal links to the HTML file:

```
anchor1  <-- this is a href link to anchor1
anchor2  <-- this is a href link to anchor2
```

When I now tried to create anchors to the actual data tables:

```
title "<a name='anchor1'></a>Data on matrix1";
proc sql;
select * from matrix1;
quit;
```

The title does not wrap the text into an anchor, but instead shows the full HTML code:

```
<a name='anchor1'></a>Data on matrix1
(matrix1 data here)
```

If I look the HTML code, I can see that the title characters are translated to be showable in HTML:

```
&lt;a name=&#39;anchor1&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;Data on matrix1
```

But how could create such an HTML anchor into the title of a proc sql query i.e. embed HTML tags into title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options here, depending on what's easiest for your general usage.

First, you could go into the template, and add for each title element's template a `prehtml` and/or `posthtml` entry.  This would mean that every time Title1 was used, you got the same anchor tag (until you reran `proc template` anyway).  That would be useful if you wanted `title#` to always have the same anchor despite sometimes variable text.

Second, you can use the `raw` style option.  `^{raw <a href="#anchor1"></a>}`, assuming your `ods escapechar` is `^`.  You also can use `^R/HTML{..}`, I believe.  See the documentation, and Cynthia Zender's classic paper [Funny Stuff in My Code](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/099-2007.pdf).  This is the better option if every title needs a different anchor (as you can specify it each time, but you also need to specify it each time).

Third, you could use the first option along with a macro variable, I believe (similar to how you did the previous contentitem) that defines the value of the anchor.  This is more 'in theory' but could be the best of the three.

Comment: +1 for the raw option.  I was going to go with the `ODSESCAPECHAR` option, but I thought I'd double check the premise of the question as I don't remember having to go to these lengths previously... I think this was just a case of syntax, unless there's something different in the OP's environment to my env...

Comment: So I first defined: `ODS ESCAPECHAR="^"`; After which `title "^{raw <a name='anchor1'></a>}Data on matrix1"`; worked like a charm. To may surprise, I could even use macro variables inside raw: `^{raw <a name='&uniqueid'></a>}`

Comment: Yep, macro variables work fine there just like anywhere else (they're just text!) as long as you're inside of outside double quotes and not singles.

Comment: Unfortunately `ods html style=Pearl;` leads to `ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access E:\SAS\config\Lev1\SASApp\sashtml.htm.` for me

Comment: @dirkhorsten Sounds like your SASUSER library path is not correct or doesn’t have the right permissions. Talk to your SAS admin to see if they can fix that.  Might be a template file in a location that’s not right also.

Answer (score 4):

In all ODS HTML-bound output, you can wrap your HTML in a `<div>...</div>` to ensure SAS renders it as the correct HTML.

To create an anchor, you use `<a name='anchorname'></a>`, so :

```
title "<div><a name='anchor1'></a></div>" ;
```

And to reference it elsewhere in your page :

```
Title "<div><a href='#anchor1'>Go to Anchor 1</a></div>" ;
```

Comment: That does work, as long as the title text is between the `</a>` and the `</div>` in the first (creating the anchor) example.  I'm a bit hesitant to do it that way given the `raw` option exists and is a bit more safe as far as likelihood of SAS keeping things the same, but it's a good option to have.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:  The below doesn't quite address the original question (I misread it), but may still be useful to some people.  As Joe points out in the comments, it looks like SAS has different approaches on how to treat HTML anchor tags in `title` statements.  Joe's answer is correct.

---

I think you simply have incorrect syntax on your anchor tag in your title statement.  This works fine for me:

```
ods html;

title "<a href='dkjfkjdf.html'>Hello</html>";

proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

ods html close;
```

[image: Results:]

I believe what you need is to move your text inside of your anchor tag (and use quotes) like so:

```
title '<a href="#anchor1">Data on matrix1</a>';
```

Comment: For some reason, that works, but if you're just trying to put an anchor tag on the title [and not make the title a hyperlink] that doesn't work (ie, putting the </a> anywhere but the end of the title).  I guess SAS must've defined a specific override just for the case of putting the title inside a hyperlink, but doesn't do it for anything else.

Comment: Actually I just re-read the question and it's specific to anchors on the same page... in which case my response is wrong =) might just delete it i think...

Comment: I'd leave it; while it's wrong for the question, I could see other people searching for this while wanting what you are showing.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the typos in the question, practically, switched a couple of "<a href" into "<a name".